# Where to store the client secret for a web extension?

Tags: authentication, firefox, oauth-2.0, firefox-addon-webextensions, secret-key

I am not quite sure where to store a client secret used in a oauth refresh token flow.

As the code for a web extension runs on a user machine, potentially everyone could use my client secret which authenticates my extension with another service 
([Strava API](https://developers.strava.com/docs/authentication/)).

I cannot see any other way than saving it in a background script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hiding your token in a file or background script is one option, storing it in another place (wrapper webservice) is another.

In the end, it's up to you.

If you don't want people to be able to see your token, store it in a wrapper service which you host yourself. The code of that service might be public as long as you don't include the token in the public version.

See also https://medium.com/poka-techblog/the-best-way-to-store-secrets-in-your-app-is-not-to-store-secrets-in-your-app-308a6807d3ed

Comment: Thanks! My issue is I don't want to host anything. The benefit of the extension is running the code in the browser only. I wanted to leverage that. But maybe I cannot get around it if I want to do it properly.

Comment: You can use base64 or something similar to hide the token, but it will be obvious that the token is base64 encrypted (and easily reversible).